# @JsonProperty of jackson2.9.9 is not working with swagger2.9.2

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, swagger, swagger-ui

I have started implementing `Swagger` with version `2.9.2` recently. It worked well without `Jackson` in other project but as I added same code with `Jackson` dependency my integration tests were started failing due to not able to covert it(XML string) into Json object.

Tried with different versions of `Jackso`n data format and swagger.

My DTO class:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Wither
public class PartsInfoDTO {
    // TODO: 08/10/18 This class should be removed after lexcom start giving remark_line instead of RemarkLine for ex.
    @JsonProperty("illustration")
    private String Illustration;
    @JsonProperty("quantity")
    private String Quantity;
    @JsonProperty("price")
    private Price Price;
    @JsonProperty("remark_line")
    private String remarkLine;
    @JsonProperty("part_number")
    @ApiModelProperty(name = "part_number")
    private String partNumber;
    @JsonProperty("denomination_line")
    private String[] denominationLine;

    public PartsInfoDTO(PartsInfo partsInfo) {
        setDenominationLine(partsInfo.getDenominationLine());
        setIllustration(partsInfo.getIllustration());
        setPartNumber(partsInfo.getPartNumber());
        setPrice(partsInfo.getPrice());
        setQuantity(partsInfo.getQuantity());
        setRemarkLine(partsInfo.getRemarkLine());
    }

}
```

My Swagger config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class PartsSwaggerConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {


    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.package.example"))
                .paths(regex(PART_INFO_API))
                .build();
    }
}
```

Error with stacktrace:

> com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character
>   ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (number, String, array,
>   object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')  at [Source:
>   (String)"1121-123453
>   1INR2ASWS03G102354Drucr";
>   line: 1, column: 2]
>
> at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1804)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:669)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportUnexpectedChar(ParserMinimalBase.java:567)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser._handleOddValue(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:1894)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser.nextToken(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:749)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:4141)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4000)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3004)
>     at
>   com.vwits.asid.etka.PartInfoControllerTest.getPartInfo(PartInfoControllerTest.java:347)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:74)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:84)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
>     at
>   com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.junit.WireMockClassRule$1.evaluate(WireMockClassRule.java:60)
>     at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)  at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)    at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)     at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)  at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
>     at
>   com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.junit.WireMockClassRule$1.evaluate(WireMockClassRule.java:70)
>     at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
>     at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)   at
>   com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
>     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
>     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
>     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)

Comment: Could you show a stacktrace with error?

Comment: Added the stackTrace of the error.

Comment: It looks like, you want to read `XML` content using `ObjectMapper`. To read `XML` `Jackson` uses [XmlMapper](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-dataformat-xml/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/xml/XmlMapper.html?is-external=true).